# How can I fix formatting (e.g., missing parentheses and punctuation) of reference entries created with biblatex-apa?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, apa6

First, I should admit I'm still fairly new to LaTeX, but I love it so far, even if it can be a bit demanding at times. Regarding my issue, I searched here in Stack Exchange and within the documentation that can be found for the CTAN packages I use (not to mention my many Web searches), but to no avail. After updating my packages with no luck, I even started digging through the biblatex and biblatex-apa files until I realized I was getting in over my head. I took other steps as well, but mostly I want any potential helpers to know that I gave a decent effort to figure this out on my own.

So, here I am. Anyway, my problem is that biblatex (more specifically, biblatex-apa) is not correctly formatting the note fields of reference entries. I've provided a working example of the LaTeX document and an example of the output below.

```
\documentclass[noextraspace, man, 12pt]{apa6}

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} 
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\title{Title} 
\shorttitle{Short title} 
\author{Name N. Namey}
\affiliation{Institution}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Blah blah blah. \cite{Texa2013}. $\SI{10}{\micro\ohm\per banana}$

\printbibliography

\appendix
\section{ }
% tables
\section{ }
% figures

\end{document}
```

[image: incorrect APA reference]

Notice the "Note" in the reference entry above. The corresponding biblatex entry is below.

```
@techreport{Texa2013,
author = {{Texas Instruments}},
title = {{LM741} operational amplifier},
year = {2013},
note = {Note},
url = {http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf},
}
```

As far as I understand the 6th edition of the Publication Manual of the APA and the CTAN documentation, the reference should look closer to the image below (ignoring the font change), where the parenthetical note field immediately follows the title and the right parenthesis is immediately followed by a period.

[image: correct APA reference]

That's all I got for now! Help?

*Edit: Slight changes for clarity.

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat{note}{\mkbibparens{#1}}`?

Comment: Almost! After adding that to the preamble of my document, it added parentheses to "Note" such that it is now "(Note)," but it still comes after the period of the title field when it should be "inside" of the title field.

Comment: Is it really a note? When it comes  before the period, it makes it look like it should just be part of the title. The use of the note field varies a lot between entry types, particularly in the rather messy APA guidelines. I'd also be careful in applying field formats globaly like that as it will change things in all notes fields in any entry type. Use the type specifier `\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{note}{ ...}`.

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure on whether it should be a note or not (properly categorizing "gray-area" documents can be tricky with APA guidelines). I was eventually going to make the note something like "Component specification sheet" or "Component data sheet," in order to describe the document's type. Also, thanks for the tip to use the type specifier.

Comment: @PLK I just reviewed the APA Publication Manual, and I'm under the impression that there should also be a note similar to "(Tech. Rep.)." I think I remember also reading something about that in the biblatex documentation, but after a brief search, I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a discussion in the comments about the merits of this venture.

Maybe you are just looking for the `titleaddon` field. It comes wrapped in square brackets though, so you might want

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibparens{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}}
```

If you insist on using the `note` field, an ad-hoc solution is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{note}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{report}
  {\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}}
  {\setunit{\addspace}
  \printfield{note}}
  {}{}
```

Comment: Hey, @moewe, thanks for the simple work-around! To recap, I added your first suggestion to my .tex document (i.e., I added the `DeclareFieldFormat` command), added a `titleaddon` field to my .bib entry, deleted the `note` field from my .bib entry, deleted auxiliary files, and recompiled everything, and the PDF now appears as desired. It's so weird because I swear this worked correctly before, but regardless, your fix is more than sufficient. Great thinking!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried your second solution, too. It also works as long as you (i.e., the "general you") leave `\DeclareFieldFormat{note}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` in the preamble. Again, good job!

Comment: @floydoom Mhhh, `\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{note}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` should be enough in the second solution. And in an example file I just ran was enough. The more general `\DeclareFieldFormat{note}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` was not necessary.

Comment: Oops! How foolish of me, @moewe. I copied only the second part of your second solution, completely missing the first command. Good catch. :)